# Shift a specific line in a text file

Tags: linux, sed

I have lines like this in a text file.

```
x :
y : long
z : 0
```

Now I want to shift the z: row up by two places(above x :). How could I do this with sed .

Comment: can you post your whole file? .. it has groups of 3 lines always?

Comment: I have many lines but they are in this order repeatedly : P: 1
N: ASYNC
I: INTR
D:Interrupts
D:The setting 
No Current Range
E:
T: bit
C: 0

Comment: Now I wanted to shift the last line by 2 lines upside

Answer (score 1):

You can use ED to move for example line 3 after line 1:

```
echo -e '3m1\nwq\n' | ed <filename>
```

For Your example it would be:

```
echo -e '3m1\n1m2\nwq\n' | ed <filename>
```

For specific text using regex instead of line numbers:

```
echo -e '/<text>/m1\n1m2\nwq\n' | ed <filename>
```

Comment: If I need to search specific text and move , What should be my approach towards this. I mean not specifically to the line numbers but specific to some text.

Comment: Cheers mate. You should also accept some answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

**file.txt:**

```
m :   
x :  
y : long  
z : 0
```

Try this:

```
$ val=`cat file.txt | grep 'z :'`
$ lineNumber=`grep -n 'x :' file.txt | awk -F: '{print $1}'`
$ sed -e '/z :/d' -e "$lineNumber"i"$val" file.txt
```

**Output:**

```
m : 
z : 0
x :
y : long
```

Comment: But There is problem with this ... If there is any value above of x: the line z: still stays top of the file which is not expected

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple `sed` command:

```
$ cat temp 
set1
x :
y : long
z : 0
set2
x :
y : long
z : 2
$ sed -n -r '/^\s*x\s*:\s*/{N;N;s/^(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)$/\3\n\1\n\2/g;p;n};p' temp
set1
z : 0
x :
y : long
set2
z : 2
x :
y : long
$
```

Using the data you have provided:

```
$ cat temp1 
P: 1
N: ASYNC
I: INTR
D:Interrupts
D:The setting No Current Range
E: 
T: bit
C: 0

P: 2
N: ASYNC
I: INTR
D:Interrupts
D:The setting No Current Range
E: 
T: bit
C: 0
$ sed -n -r '/^\s*E\s*:\s*/{N;N;s/^(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)$/\3\n\1\n\2/g;p;n};p' temp1
P: 1
N: ASYNC
I: INTR
D:Interrupts
D:The setting No Current Range
C: 0
E: 
T: bit

P: 2
N: ASYNC
I: INTR
D:Interrupts
D:The setting No Current Range
C: 0
E: 
T: bit
$
```

Edit1:  explanation

`sed -n -r '/^\s*E\s*:\s*/{N;N;s/^(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)$/\3\n\1\n\2/g;p;n};p' temp1`

`-n` switch turns off default auto printing

`-r` enables ERE (Extended Regular Expressions)

`/^\s*E\s*:\s*/` this ensures the following commands in `{}` work only when the current line matches the regex `/^\s*E\s*:\s*/` i.e the current line must match the `E :` text which is the line we want

if the current matches the expression the following is performed: `{N;N;s/^(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)$/\3\n\1\n\2/g;p;n};p`

`N` reads next line and appends it to current line separating both by `\n`, hence `N;N` reads next 2 lines and then

`s/^(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)$/\3\n\1\n\2/g` swaps the 3 lines according to desired order

`p` prints the 3 lines`

`n` skips to next line processing skipping execution of `p` after that

last `p` is needed for lines not matching `/^\s*E\s*:\s*/`

Comment: Thanks @Ritesh, Do you mind explaining me the sed command in this scenario?

Comment: @VenkataVamshi yes sure .. give me few mins to add an explanantion

Comment: Sure, Thanks!!@Ritesh

Comment: @VenkataVamshi was amidst some work, added explanation now